# NodeJS - Socket.IO Setup: served static content no handshake (Ubuntu on Rackspace Cloud Server)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rackspace-cloud

I have installed on Rackspace with Ubuntu node.js with Socket.IO

When I tried a simple server app and try to use client request I got 'served static content' only instead of hand shake. In browser in debug I can see "Hello S..." and on server side:

```
# node socket-server.js 
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
```

I'm not sure where to start look for a problem (same script works in local development)

Why node.js serve only static content and doesn't handshake?

Iptables allow 8866 port:# iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8866 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8866
```

Here is a simple server app 'socket-server.js':

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io');

// Start the server at port 8866
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

        // Send HTML headers and message
        res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});
server.listen(8866);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socket = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connection', function(client){

        // Create periodical which ends a message to the client every 5 seconds
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
                client.send('This is a message from the server!  ' + new Date().getTime());
        },5000);

        // Success!  Now listen to messages to be received
        client.on('message',function(event){
                console.log('Received message from client!',event);
        });
        client.on('disconnect',function(){
                clearInterval(interval);
                console.log('Server has disconnected');
        });

});
```

Here is a simple client (SERVERDOMAIN is replaced with real domain):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://SERVERDOMAIN:8866/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

    // Create SocketIO instance
    var socket = io.connect('SERVERDOMAIN:8866');
    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('connect',function() {
        log('<span style="color:green;">Client has connected to the server!</span>');
    });
    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('message',function(data) {
        log('Received a message from the server:  ' + data);
    });
    // Add a disconnect listener
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
        log('<span style="color:red;">The client has disconnected!</span>');
    });

    // Sends a message to the server via sockets
    function sendMessageToServer(message) {
        socket.send(message);
        log('<span style="color:#888">Sending "' + message + '" to the server!</span>');
    }

    // Outputs to console and list
    function log(message) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = message;
        document.getElementById('message-list').appendChild(li);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Messages will appear below (and in the console).</p><br />
<ul id="message-list"></ul>
<ul style="margin:20px 0 0 20px;">
    <li>Type <code>socket.disconnect()</code> to disconnect</li>
    <li>Type <code>socket.connect()</code> to reconnect</li>
    <li>Type <code>sendMessageToServer('Your Message')</code> to send a message to the server</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if there's an error on your page the output stops after "debug - served static content /socket.io.js" - are you sure your clientside code is working?

Answer (score 3):

In your client code try this

```
var socket = io.connect('http://SERVERDOMAIN:8866');
```

This problem is mainly associated with incorrect url.

Comment: Thank you for advice but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing my socket.io application with a couple of Android ( phone and tablet ) devices along with desktop browsers on a **wifi connection**. Based on ***beNerd's answer above*** I changed my

```
io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

to

```
io.connect('http://192.168.5.3:3000'); // ip address of machine where the node.js app is running.
```

and it worked.

Hope the answer is helpful to users testing their NodeJS and Socket.IO application with a Wifi connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have end up with completely new server installation and everything is working fine now.

I have used Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) and install node.js with socket.io

For the client I'm using local copy of socket.io.js with Flash file.

;-)